# Do columns have to be named manually in pandas?

Tags: python, file, pandas

I have a text file that contains feature names for a dataset. I need to import this file and then load the dataset into columns that correspond to the feature names. I do the usual and import pandas and load the file with pd.read_csv and I get a vertical listing of all the feature names with a 0,1,2 etc in front. What I'm wondering is, is there anyway for me to assign these names to a column without doing it manually? I thought I could get them into a list and iterate but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

I have done a good bit of googling but couldn't find my exact problem anywhere and can only see columns being assigned manually.

Comment: `df` always have a column, after loading you can assign directly like so `df.columns = ['col1', 'col2'...]`

Comment: OK, so if my featurenames.txt file has id, age, race, sex, etc. then I can't pull them out with a function, I'd have to just manually enter df.columns = ['id', 'age', 'race', 'sex'...]? If that's the case then that's fine, I just keep getting caught up with the fact that I can't load them somehow.

Comment: Yes that'll work do long as the length of list and number of columns matches

Answer (score 0):

So if I have dataframe name `feature` and a list of feature name corresponding to column. You can do it as following. I provide example with 2 columns.

```
import pandas as pd
feature_name = ['feature1', 'feature2']
t = zip(feature.columns.values, feature_name)
replace_dict = dict((x, y) for (x, y) in t)
feature.rename(columns=replace_dict, inplace=True)
```

Or just do `feature.columns = ['feature1', 'feature1']`

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining myself very well, is there a way to do this without typing in each feature e.g. feature_name = ['feature1', 'feature2'] - if I had 200 features then that would be very time consuming.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Probably saving feature into a text file and read it to list would be one way that I can think of.